# Maintain Excel dynamic table references in another sheet when re-creating table from a new data connection

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

In Excel, I have a table that populates from a SQL Server Query in another tab. When I change the query I want to be able to update the data table while maintaining cell references to that table.

The only way I have been able to get the content of the table to change based on the query in the other tab is to recreate the table. Problem is when I recreate the table, I loose all the dynamic cell references to that table in my other worksheets.

This Subroutine populates an empty workbook with the data I need from a SQL query in a Tab called Query:

```
Sub PopulateTable_GLP()

Set cSQL = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Query").Range("B2")  '  Sets cSQL to the SQL query
    nWhen = 0
    cWhen = ""
    cConn = "ODBC;DSN=GLP"


    With Sheets("GLP_Results").ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "ODBC;DSN=GLP;Description=GLP;DATABASE=GLP" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandText = cSQL
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_GLP"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

This function creates the sheet before populating the table if it does not exist and clears the sheet before populating if it does:

```
Sub Create_GL_Results()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "GLP_Results"
    Range("A1").Select

    Call PopulateTable_GLP


ErrorHandler:

    Sheets("GLP_Results").Cells.Clear
    Sheets("GLP_Results").Select

    Call PopulateTable_GLP

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I tried to turn off Screen updating and automatic calculation while this was occurring to stop the other sheets from replacing all the dynamic references with #REF! but that did not seem to help.

I do not need to re-create the table but I do need to be able to change the query in the underlying connection which without loosing my dynamic references. The column names I reference won't be changing as the query is updated but the way those columns are populated could.

Comment: Just change the `CommandText` and refresh?

Answer (score 0):

You could include this statement:

```
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

If that is too much refreshment, you could just pull up the table in question and refresh that.